# @RepositoryEventHandler is not getting invoked

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have created a simple repository for my app users:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
public interface AppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUserModel, Long> {

    List<AppUserModel> findByUsername(@Param("username") String username);

}
```

However, I need to take care of password encryption before a new user gets inserted. For this I implemented a `@RepositoryEventHandler`:

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(AppUserModel.class)
public class AppUserService {

    @HandleBeforeSave
    public void handleProfileSave(AppUserModel appUserModel) {
        System.out.println("Before save ..");
    }

    @HandleBeforeCreate
    public void register(AppUserModel appUserModel) {
        System.out.println("Before create ..");
    }

}
```

The problem is that none of those two event handlers are getting executed. As a result `AppUserModel` is tried to be persisted but fails because no salt (for the password) has been generated and set - that's how I can tell that the `JpaRepository<AppUserModel, Long>` is working so far.

```
{
"cause": {
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
            "message": "ERROR: null value in column "password_salt" violates not-null constraint Detail: Failing row contains (26, 2017-11-18 21:21:47.534, 2017-11-18 21:21:47.534, f, asd, null, haha@gmx.at)."
        },
    "message": "could not execute statement"
    },
    "message": "could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [password_salt]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me that you just need to create `AppUserService` bean. The easiest option would be to annotate it with `@Component`

```
@Component
@RepositoryEventHandler(AppUserModel.class)
public class AppUserService {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Oh. I just found another solution that uses `@Bean` in yet another configuration class. That worked too and I will post that as another answer but your solution is of course much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be providing the bean from within another configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    AppUserEventHandler appUserService() {
        return new AppUserEventHandler();
    }
}
```

However, I prefer the solution provided by @varren.